# How can I deconvolve a response function and a Gaussian to find the unknown original signal?

Tags: python, scipy, fft, deconvolution

This is my first post so I apologize for any errors!

I'm trying to deconvolve a waveform (response function) and a Gaussian [that's fit to the response] to get the original signal, which is unknown.

Essentially, if I convolve the original signal (representing some scattering function onto a detector) with a Gaussian, I will get the response function (the final waveform that is observed by the detector). The problem is that I don't know what the original signal is.

[Here's a plot of what I have so far -- orange is Gaussian, blue is the waveform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k41Ge.png) The size of both the Gaussian and waveform arrays is 128.

I played around with scipy.deconvolve but ended up getting the original signal [as a 1-element array instead of a 128-element array like I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbU4y.png).

Is there a way I can use FFT or iFFT to get back the original, unknown signal instead of using scipy.deconvolve?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you look into Wiener filtering? That is the simplest approach you can use, it's fairly trivial to implement yourself. If its results are not good enough, you'll have to try more complicated methods.

Comment: `scipy.signal.deconvolve` doesn't do any boundary extension, so its output is `length(signal) - length(divisor) + 1` (using the nomenclature of the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html)). You might get better results if you cut the long tail off the Gaussian.

Comment: Awesome, thank you both so much! I will try both :)